# SharePoint Search - new content source isn't displaying file titles in search results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

I recently added a new file share to the content sources.  I'm able to search for these new files successfully.  However, for some reason, this new content source's files don't have titles displayed in the search results.  If I hover over and select "Edit", I can open them fine.  The `Title` property is set to `Basic:displaytitle` just as the other content source is.  The service account has full access to the file share.  What else could be causing this?

Edit: Another thing I've noticed is that it's only happening for Excel documents.